# Spring @ControllerAdvice Handler exception is not picking NoHandlerFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, http-status-code-404

I am handling exceptions using @ControllerAdvice, I have on @ControllerAdvice for my rest controllers and one for the non-rest controllers, they are picking exceptions for Exception.class but they are not picking NoHandlerFoundException.class.

We are using Spring 4.3.7.RELEASE, Java Config, Apache 8.5.12.

Below is MyWebInitializer class

```
public class MyWebInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {      

        super.onStartup(servletContext);

        servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
        servletContext.addListener(new SpringSessionListener());

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher1 =
        servletContext.addServlet("blackwellsjspservlet", new JspServlet());
        dispatcher1.setLoadOnStartup(3);
        dispatcher1.addMapping("*.do");
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringRootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringWebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
      protected String getServletName() {
        return "blackwellsmvcdispatcherservlet";
      }

    //Added to allow customised NoHandlerFoundPage
    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        boolean done = registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true"); // -> true
        if(!done) throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    //Added to register a default profile
    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createServletApplicationContext() {
        WebApplicationContext context = (WebApplicationContext) super.createServletApplicationContext();
        ((ConfigurableEnvironment) context.getEnvironment()).setDefaultProfiles("production");

        return context;
    }
}
```

My SpringWebConfig is:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/");
        viewResolver.setViewNames("*.jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }


    @Bean
    public Loader<?> templateLoader(){
        return new ServletLoader(servletContext);
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomSpringExtension springExtension() {
        return new CustomSpringExtension();
    }



    @Bean
    public PebbleEngine pebbleEngine() {
        return new PebbleEngine.Builder()
                .loader(this.templateLoader()).cacheActive(false)
                .extension(springExtension())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver pebbleViewResolver() {
        PebbleViewResolver viewResolver = new PebbleViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/patternLab/");
        viewResolver.setPebbleEngine(pebbleEngine());
        viewResolver.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 5);
        viewResolver.setViewNames("*.html");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    /**
     * Bean for ResourceMessageBundle
     * basename and folder resources/locale/messages. i.g. messages_en_GB.properties,messages_en_US.properties
     * @author Henrique Droog
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource(){
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:locale/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

        return messageSource;
    }

    /**
     * Bean for LocalResolver
     * set en as a default locale
     * @author Henrique Droog
     * @date 09.03.2017
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
        CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
        resolver.setCookieName("myLocaleCookie");
        resolver.setCookieMaxAge(4800);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor(){
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }


    @Profile({"production-api","dev-api"})
        @ComponentScan(basePackages  = { "uk.co.blackwells.controllers", "uk.co.blackwells.rest.controller"})
    public static class ProductionAPIWebConfig {

    }

    @Profile({"production","dev","default"})
    @ComponentScan(basePackages  = { "uk.co.blackwells.controllers","uk.co.blackwells.rest.controller"})
    public static class ProductionWebConfig {

    }

    @Profile({"test"})
    @ComponentScan(basePackages  = { "uk.co.blackwells.controllers","uk.co.blackwells.rest.controller"})
    public static class TestWebConfig {

    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(sessionInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns("/api/**", "/restful/**");

        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("mylocale");
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);

    }

    @Bean
    public SessionInterceptor sessionInterceptor() {
        return new SessionInterceptor();
    }

    @Bean
    public Validator validatorFactory () {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

My controller advices for non rest controllers:

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations=Controller.class)
public class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandlerController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalDefaultExceptionHandlerController.class);
    ErrorList errorList;

    /**
     * This init binder register a custom editor to trim all fields coming
     * from html
     * @param binder
     */
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder ( WebDataBinder binder )
    {
        StringTrimmerEditor stringtrimmer = new StringTrimmerEditor(true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, stringtrimmer);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleNotFoundException(HttpServletRequest req, NoHandlerFoundException ex) {

        ErrorMessage erMsg = new ErrorMessage();
        erMsg.setError(ex.getMessage());
        erMsg.setStackTrace(stackTrace);
        erMsg.setException(ex);

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("errorMessageObject", erMsg);

        model.setViewName("pages/error-404.html");

        return model;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView handleAllException(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) throws Exception {

        // Rethrow annotated exceptions or they will be processed here instead.
        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(ex.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class) != null)
            throw ex;


        ErrorMessage erMsg = new ErrorMessage();
        erMsg.setError(exceptionCode);
        erMsg.setStackTrace(stackTrace);
        erMsg.setException(ex);

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("errorMessageObject", erMsg);
        model.addObject("errMsg", ex.getMessage());
        model.addObject("exceptionCode", exceptionCode);

        model.setViewName("pages/error-500.html");

        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/SessionError"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sessionError() {
        return "pages/error-500.html";
    }
}
```

For rest controllers:

```
@RestControllerAdvice(annotations=RestController.class)
public class ApiExceptionHandlerController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiExceptionHandlerController.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex){
        logger.error("API Exception: {}", ex.getMessage(), ex);
        logger.error("Path:{}, IP:{}", req.getServletPath(),  req.getRemoteAddr());

         ApiError apiError = 
                  new ApiError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Internal server error", ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getStatus());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotFoundException(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex){
        logger.error("API NoHandlerFoundException: {}", ex.getMessage(), ex);
        logger.error("Path:{}, IP:{}", req.getServletPath(),  req.getRemoteAddr());
        ex.printStackTrace();

         ApiError apiError = 
                  new ApiError(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ex.getMessage(), ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Both controller advices were picking NoHandlerFoundException until sometime back. I had a look in the history changes for these files but they haven't been changed for a while. I think maybe this part of the code

```
@Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        boolean done = registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true"); // -> true
        if(!done) throw new RuntimeException();
    }
```

is being overridden for some other code, but I can't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 1):

If you used Spring Boot:

In the org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet class there is a variable called throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound. If this is set to true a method called noHandlerFound will throw a NoHandlerFoundException. Your exception handler will now catch it.

Add this property to your application.properties file: spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true

Comment: Thank you Dave, unfortunately I am not using Spring Boot. I also set throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound as true in y web initializer which extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer. Anyway I will think if I can have a try using some properties instead of web initializer.